# Urls and file organization in a Django project

Tags: python, django, django-urls, code-structure

I am developing a website with django, and I don't know how I should structure my project.

Let's say that my project tree is:

```
main
  ├───_main
  |   ├── __init__.py
  |   ├── settings.py
  |   ├── urls.py
  |   └── wsgi.py
  ├───_accounts
  |   ├── models.py
  |   ├── forms.py
  |   ├── urls.py
  |   ├── views.py
  |   └── ...
  └───_website
      ├──_static
      |  └──_website
      |     ├── css (...)
      |     └── js  (...)
      ├──_templates
      |  └──_website
      |     └── (html files...)
      ├── urls.py
      ├── views.py
      └── ...
```

I have two apps ('accounts' and 'website') in my project 'main'. The 'accounts' app implements the user model and the authentication process. The 'website' app controls non-model related stuff, like home page and so on. Of course, there will be more apps...

At this moment, all the web files (html, css, js...) are stores in 'website' (static / templates folders), and website/urls.py handles all urls.

```
# website/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from .views import index
from accounts.views import LoginView, LogoutView, RegisterView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', index, name="index"),

    # Accounts
    url(r'^login/', LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    url(r'^logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    url(r'^register/', RegisterView.as_view(), name="register"),
]
```

It makes sense to me that user-related web files like login form, register form, etc., should be store in static and templates directories inside 'accounts', and urls handling (like '/login', '/logout', '/register'...) should be managed by accounts/urls.py. Is it correct? If so, how can I do it?

The only thing that comes into my mind (not tested) is to include every the urls.py file from every app in main/urls.py:

```
# main/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('website.urls', namespace="website")),
    url(r'^', include('accounts.urls', namespace="accounts")),
]
```

but it seems weird... What is the right way?

Comment: you can put static and templates folder inside main Main project directory and inside those folder make app folder to put specific app related files else when app will increase you have to create static and templates folder in every app folder

Comment: For now I have switched to the 'main/urls.py' solution. It works fine and I can now use applications namespaces. I have created 'static' and 'templates' folders in 'account' and copied inside the account-related files (html forms...). I think it will make the apps more portable accross projects. However, for simplicity, I will continue working with htmls in the 'website' app. I don't know if it is a good practice, though.

Comment: you can put files based on app, Apps will have their own template / static / URL files inside that will give you portability but not needed for most cases else like i said before make common template and static folder and inside make app folders for respective files with different URL for different App

Comment: Check this link it will help you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/reusable-apps/

Comment: Thank you Vicmathur. It's good to know the "official" way, and it seems that now my project structure is not far from it.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it must be

```
main
  ├───_main
  |   ├── __init__.py
  |   ├── settings.py
  |   ├── urls.py
  |   └── wsgi.py
  ├───_accounts
  |   ├── models.py
  |   ├── forms.py
  |   ├── urls.py
  |   ├── views.py
  |   └── ...
  |
template-
  |
static
  └──
      ├── css
      ├── js
      └── ...
```

Comment: I though that Django apps should be portable. So, as I have a 'website' app, shouldn't the web front-end files be inside of it?

Comment: It doens't master, depend your applications required, Just is my structer project for you prefer